# Trying to make a image switcher (I don't know how to call it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use jQuery to make an image switcher. I want it to be done in a div.

This is what I have: `<div id="main-pic"></div>` which means I completely have no idea how to do it...

Anyway, here is what I need:

[image: Requirement]

## If the image appears to be too small, and if you don't mind, zoom in your browser

Comment: Slider, Carousel, image slider, etc. there are hundreds of them. Listing any of them here wouldn't be very useful due to the fact that they come and go so often.

Comment: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a carousel. One example of such is this [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel)